# Query on vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a character vector, just want to know couple of things about this  vector c("1", "2", "3"):

- Can it be converted to a numeric vector?
- Can it be added to the vector c(3, 4, 5) directly using a + operator?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
as.numeric(c("1", "2", "3")) +  c(3, 4, 5)
[1] 4 6 8
```